# Typescript fetch()'s header type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have something like:

```
  const request: Partial<Request> = {
    method,
    cache,
    redirect,
    headers: {} as Headers,
  };

  if (...) {
    request.headers['content-type'] = contentType;
  }
```

However, TS complains `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`, probably because of `Partial`.

If I don't include `Partial<>`, I get:

```
Type '{ method: string; cache: RequestCache; redirect: RequestRedirect; headers: Headers; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Request': credentials, destination, integrity, isHistoryNavigation, and 15 more.
```

Why can't TS infer that `headers` is already defined?

Comment: what is your condition?

Comment: It checks if it's anything but a GET request and that `contentType` is truthy.

Comment: Two observations: **1)** Header values should be acessed using the [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get) method and not an index signature **2)** You can still make this work with `Partial<Request>`, you need to tell the TS compiler that you're certain `headers` is non-null with the non-null assertion operator (e.g. `request.headers!.get('content-type')`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Partial<Request>` which would make all of the properties optional you can use

```
Pick<Request, "method" | "cache" | "redirect" | "headers">
```

or define an object and use it's keys to pick from the Request interface for static type checking

```
const request = {
  method: "GET",
  cache: "no-cache" as const,
  redirect: "follow" as const,
  headers: {} as Headers,
};

if (true) {
  request.headers["content-type"] = "text/html";
}


const myRequest: Pick<Request, keyof typeof request> = request;
```